# how to prevent window.print to show print dialog in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing, progressive-web-apps

We are developing a cross-platform progressive web app using react-js and in order to print, we are going to use window.print but everytime it shows print dialog which is frustrating.

I know that for security reasons, browsers don't allow window.print to print without showing dialog in order to get print permission from user.

I wonder is there any settings that user can allow a trusted web page to do the printing stuff or anyway to bypass it?

I considered many other questions that were the same and there was also only one solution that only worked for IE.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: No there isn't a way around it.

Comment: If cross browser compatibility with IE is the reason you are using window.print, one option would be to detect and only use window.print if it detects trident (or whatever the IE engine is called) and otherwise use a separate method for non-IE.

Comment: If you are in control of the machines you can set the flag when you open chrome to disable it. `--disable-print-preview.`